# Search in MongoDB - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm implementing Search capabilities in my Node.js application as part of to enable text search I want to have some fields similar to

```
{ title : "this is fun" ,
  _keywords : [ "this" , "is" , "fun" ]
}
```

How to get _keywords fields as shown from Node.Js? Is there any way to have _keywords corresponding to title as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I could make out from your question, I guess you wish to split the `title` into `_keywords`.

You can achieve this in node.js by doing something like.

```
_keywords = title.split(" ");
```

Comment: Hi - I tried this and what happens is it gets stored in DB like _keywords: "this is fun" but I want to store it as _keywords: ["this" , "is" , "fun"] so that I can do searching on top of it. Could you please help me ?

Comment: did you tried, what i suggested. Call split on title. It would work.

Comment: Can you show what you coded. Perhaps that could help fix the issue :)

Comment: Hi

I'm passing the following value parameter

{"keyWords":"1001 1002 1003"}

and have following statement to convert it as array

objShop._keywords  = objReq.keyWords.split(" ");

but in DB what I see is "_keywords" : "1001,1002,1003" but i'm expecting "_keywords" : ["1001","1002","1003"]